# Is 1.3s Slow for a Query with GPS, Text, & Ranked Keywords?

Tags: mysql

I've got a MySQL database with about 80K products, 300 store locations, and pricing info.  Some products have prices, some don't.  I'm running search on the product names (text), tags associated with them (text), ranks (integers), omit_tags that searches & products that don't go together, and geolocation based on a users location and distance they specify from the stores location.  My search times are averaging 1.3s to return 10 results.  Would this be considered slow?

Here's what my query looks like.

`````
SELECT DISTINCT t3.prod_id, 
                t3.awaiting_approval, 
                t3.brand, 
                t3.prod_name, 
                t3.size, 
                t3.units, 
                t3.category, 
                t3.image, 
                t3.url, 
                t3.quantity, 
                t3.rank, 
                t3.word_count, 
                t3.word_count 
FROM   ((SELECT item_info_mem.prod_id, 
                item_info_mem.awaiting_approval, 
                item_info_mem.prod_name, 
                item_info_mem.brand, 
                item_info_mem.size, 
                item_info_mem.units, 
                item_info_mem.category, 
                (SELECT rank 
                 FROM   search_tags_mem 
                 WHERE  prod_id = item_info_mem.prod_id 
                        AND tag = "bread" 
                 ORDER  BY rank 
                 LIMIT  1)                                                    AS
                rank, 
                (SELECT image 
                 FROM   images_mem 
                 WHERE  prod_id = item_info_mem.prod_id 
                 ORDER  BY id 
                 LIMIT  1)                                                    AS
                image, 
                (SELECT url 
                 FROM   urls_mem 
                 WHERE  prod_id = item_info_mem.prod_id 
                        AND disabled IS NULL 
                 ORDER  BY id DESC 
                 LIMIT  1)                                                    AS
                        url, 
                (SELECT quantity 
                 FROM   shopping_list_mem 
                 WHERE  user_id = "1" 
                        AND prod_id = item_info_mem.prod_id 
                 ORDER  BY id 
                 LIMIT  1)                                                    AS
                        quantity, 
                ( Substrcount(Lcase(item_info_mem.prod_name), Lcase("bread"))
                  + Substrcount(Lcase(item_info_mem.brand), Lcase("bread")) ) AS
                        word_count, 
                ( Substrcheck(Lcase(item_info_mem.prod_name), 
                    Lcase(item_info_mem.brand), Lcase("bread")) )             AS
                        word_count_unique 
         FROM   item_info_mem 
         WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT id 
                            FROM   search_tags_omit_mem 
                            WHERE  prod_id = item_info_mem.prod_id 
                                   AND tag = "bread" 
                            ORDER  BY id DESC 
                            LIMIT  1) 
                AND ( item_info_mem.prod_name REGEXP "bread" 
                       OR item_info_mem.brand REGEXP "bread" ) 
                AND EXISTS(SELECT scans_mem.scan_id 
                           FROM   scans_mem, 
                                  stores_mem 
                           WHERE  scans_mem.price IS NOT NULL 
                                  AND scans_mem.expired IS NULL 
                                  AND item_info_mem.prod_id = scans_mem.prod_id
                                  AND NOT 
                          EXISTS (SELECT 
        user_stores_disabled_mem.user_id 
                                                  FROM 
                                 user_stores_disabled_mem 
                                 , 
stores_mem 
WHERE  scans_mem.store_id = 
stores_mem.id 
AND 
user_stores_disabled_mem.chain = 
stores_mem.chain 
AND 
user_stores_disabled_mem.user_id = 
1) 
AND ( Sqrt(Pow(111 * (stores_mem.gps_lat 
- 40.748080 
), 2) 
+ Pow(111 * (stores_mem.gps_lng - 
-73.990533) * 
Cos( 
40.748080 / 
57.3) 
, 
2)) <= (SELECT user_mem.distance 
  FROM   user_mem 
  WHERE  id = 1)) 
AND stores_mem.id = scans_mem.store_id)) 
UNION ALL 
(SELECT item_info_mem.prod_id, 
item_info_mem.awaiting_approval, 
item_info_mem.prod_name, 
item_info_mem.brand, 
item_info_mem.size, 
item_info_mem.units, 
item_info_mem.category, 
search_tags_mem.rank, 
(SELECT image 
FROM   images_mem 
WHERE  prod_id = item_info_mem.prod_id 
ORDER  BY id 
LIMIT  1)                                                    AS image,
(SELECT url 
FROM   urls_mem 
WHERE  prod_id = item_info_mem.prod_id
AND disabled IS NULL 
ORDER  BY id DESC 
LIMIT  1)                                                    AS 
url, 
(SELECT quantity 
FROM   shopping_list_mem 
WHERE  user_id = "1" 
AND prod_id = item_info_mem.prod_id 
ORDER  BY id 
LIMIT  1)                                                    AS 
quantity, 
( Substrcount(Lcase(item_info_mem.prod_name), Lcase("bread")) 
+ Substrcount(Lcase(item_info_mem.brand), Lcase("bread")) ) AS 
word_count, 
( Substrcheck(Lcase(item_info_mem.prod_name), 
Lcase(item_info_mem.brand), Lcase("bread")) )             AS 
word_count_unique 
FROM   item_info_mem, 
search_tags_mem, 
scans_mem, 
stores_mem 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT id 
FROM   search_tags_omit_mem 
WHERE  prod_id = item_info_mem.prod_id 
AND tag = "bread" 
ORDER  BY id DESC 
LIMIT  1) 
AND scans_mem.price IS NOT NULL 
AND scans_mem.expired IS NULL 
AND item_info_mem.prod_id = search_tags_mem.prod_id 
AND search_tags_mem.tag = "bread" 
AND item_info_mem.prod_id = scans_mem.prod_id 
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT user_stores_disabled_mem.user_id 
FROM   user_stores_disabled_mem, 
stores_mem 
WHERE  scans_mem.store_id = stores_mem.id 
AND user_stores_disabled_mem.chain = 
stores_mem.chain 
AND user_stores_disabled_mem.user_id = 1) 
AND ( Sqrt(Pow(111 * (stores_mem.gps_lat - 40.748080), 2) 
+ Pow(111 * (stores_mem.gps_lng - -73.990533) * Cos( 
40.748080 / 
57.3) 
, 
2)) <= (SELECT user_mem.distance 
FROM   user_mem 
WHERE  id = 1)) 
AND stores_mem.id = scans_mem.store_id)) t3 
ORDER  BY -rank DESC, 
          word_count_unique DESC, 
          word_count DESC, 
          Field(t3.category, "food", "grocery", "pantry, household & pets",
          "confectionery and grocery") DESC, 
          Length(prod_name), 
          brand 
LIMIT  0, 10 

````
`````

Comment: Is it *fast enough for your purposes*? If so, then no, it's not slow. If not, then yes, it's slow.

Comment: That's true.  I'm wondering if this is the sort of performance one can expect when GPS is involved in a MySQL query or if I can do much better.  I'm using memory tables running on a machine with 72 cores.  I'm not even using 2% of the cpu and everything is in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot of reasons why the script being `fast` or `slow`. 
`PC Specs capabilities`, `DB Server version`, `DB Structure including indexes`, `Query structure` also with network connection between `server` and `client`.

If you are asking `Would this be considered slow?` with `80k` records my answer is `NO`

This Guide will help you about [Query Optimization](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/mysql-performance-identifying-long-queries/).